# Google Chrome Snippets: Identifier '...' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, es6-class

I'm using **Google Chrome's Snippets** (inside Dev Tools) for some JS development and testing.

When declaring ES6 classes, the console throws an

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Foo' has already been declared at...

after the first time it was run.

```
class Foo {
constructor(val) {
        this.bar = val;
    }
}

var f = new Foo('myVal');
console.log(f.bar); // prints 'myVal'
```

I did some research and found out that wrapping the code in a block scope with `{}` would help in avoiding this problem.

But when I do this, although the code runs without error, Chrome doesn't recognize any subsequent edits that I may do to my code.

So, if I changed the above code to the following:

```
{
    class Foo {
    constructor(val) {
            this.bar = val;
        }
    }
}

var f = new Foo('myVal');
console.log(f.bar); // prints 'myVal'
```

So far everything works fine.

Now, I realize that there is a problem with my class and I change the code to the following:

```
{
    class Foo {
    constructor(val) {
            this.bar = 'MyHardcodedVal'; // Here is the changed code
        }
    }
}

var f = new Foo('myVal');
console.log(f.bar); // STILL prints 'myVal'
```

As you can see, the edits I made to my class are not taking effect.

It appears that Google Chrome has put my code in a sandbox that is immune from my editing.

A way to look behind the scene and see what Google Chrome is doing is to introduce an intentional mistake into the code and then click on the source of the mistake that Chrome shows in the console. There you will see that the code for the class is still the old one and not changed at all, while the code that has been outside of the block scope is up to date.

[image: A few pieces of important information are highlighted: (let) The intentional mistake / ('hardcoded') The change in my class / (VM157) Top and down where you can click to see how the code looks like behind the scenes]

[image: Here you can see that behind the scene the edit to the code that was in block scope is not existent]

I could always close the tab I am working in and open it again, but that isn't practical.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a sane way to use Snippets for such tests?

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: It's unclear what actually happened since the same always works for me when I use {}-wrapped code. BTW {} are braces, not block quotes, and your second snippet isn't wrapped. I think the question is incomplete. So far it sounds like your first incorrect attempt is still residing in the global context, and you thought it'll magically disappear, which it won't, of course.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm , sorry, I thought that was clear, but you are right, it wasn't. I should have put more time into explaining the situation in full. Please, have a look now and see if you can reproduce the behavior I'm facing. Thanks!

Comment: you cannot re-declare `let`, `const` and `class`. Declaration with the same name will throw that error that you see. If you did not declared it before, then it must have been declared somewhere in your global-scoped code. Clearing the console does not clear the "declaration memory".

Comment: Everything should be enclosed in {}, not just the class declaration, and you need to use const/let inside, not var. The code outside of the block is using the outer (global) scope. This is how JavaScript works.

Comment: Thanks, @wOxxOm. Putting everything in block quotes worked like a charm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based off the comments, it sounds like the solution is to wrap the entire [snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets) in braces.

```js
{
  class Foo {
    constructor(val) {
      this.bar = 'MyHardcodedVal'; // Here is the changed code
    }
  }
  var f = new Foo('myVal');
  console.log(f.bar); // STILL prints 'myVal'
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Thank you for taking the time.